# Could you write directly on an external hdd drive with owncloud reading the files?

Tags: web-server, server, hard-drive, filesystem, owncloud

I have a small owncloud server on Raspbian and owncloud stores all data on an external hdd drive wich is connected to the raspbeerry pi. Right now I would like to upload all my movies, music etc.  to my owncloud, but as one could expect this takes ages (approx. 150GB). Would it be possible to shut down the raspberry and plug the drive directly into my desktop and write the files to the correct directories? Or would this result in errors regarding reading,writing permissions or anything else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would say its perfectly possible to do this.

I use my external hard drive for torrents and whenever I need to transfer unfinished torrents from pc to laptop I directly transfer by removing the hard disk.Never had a problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I just feared that the server mifht lack the permissions to open the files another user put there. I'll try it and accept it then

Comment: Did it work? The last time I tried something similar, owncloud was not very happy about new files appearing in its data directory (even though they were owned by the correct user). It just had problems reading them, especially the music files.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes this is possible** as SteveIrwin says.

I'd just like to add that after you have manually copied your files into the data directory, you'll need to **change the owner and group** to the appropriate user running your server instance. For example, I'm running my ownCloud on an Apache server under the "www-data" user and group, so I do:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data "myfoldername"
```

**to allow ownCloud to recognise the folder, subfolders and files** and be able to edit them.

In order **to find your Apache user**, run:

```
ps axo user,group,comm | grep apache2
```

which should give you an output like:

```
root     root     apache2
www-data www-data apache2
www-data www-data apache2
www-data www-data apache2
www-data www-data apache2
www-data www-data apache2
www-data www-data apache2
www-data www-data apache2
www-data www-data apache2
www-data www-data apache2
www-data www-data apache2
```

with the **user in the first column** (www-data) and the **group in the second column** (www-data).

Comment: Hello and welcome! Is ownCloud not keeping some kind of a database for the files it handles? (I remember only very remotely that this was suggested in another topic.) If so would it not be necessary to run some "update db" tool after manually copying files?

Comment: Hi Ghanima. Yes ownCloud does have a database, typically mysql or sqlite, depending on what you first choose in the setup wizard. I don't know the full detail of how it updates, but if you change the owner and group as described, your files will be recognised. There must be already some sort of update script running. I've just tested this on my server.

Comment: ...and will that update automatically or does it need to be triggered upon putting some files in there behind its back?

Comment: yes it will, sorry i submitted my last comment by mistake before confirming that it updates automatically in the background